# Delete missing files from workspace using SVN ant

Tags: svn, ant, svnkit

I checkout files from the SVN repository, replaced content for few files and deleted few files. Now I want to commit all the changes including the deleted file. I am using below code but the deleted files still remains in the repository. Please guide.

```
<svn svnkit="true" javahl="false" username="${svn.user}" password="${svn.pass}">
            <add>
                <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.txt" />
                </fileset>
            </add>
            <commit message="Committing changes..">
                <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.txt" />
                </fileset>
            </commit>
</svn>
```

How can SVN ant delete task be used for the same? since by default SVN delete task would delete any matching pattern set which is not expected.